# EPiServer vs EPiServer with Page Type Builder

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, content-management-system, episerver, episerver-6

When creating properties and page types through admin mode in EPiServer, it's quite easy to understand how the database is written to in order to update the configuration of the website. But with page type builder, however, if it's as easy as writing...

```
[PageTypeProperty]
public virtual string MainBody { get; set; }
```

...to create a new property - at what point is this stored in the datbase? Runtime? Compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page Type Builder will create the properties at runtime.

Comment: If you haven't touched the classes and want quicker startup up you can disable PTB doing it's work in web.config: <configSections>    
    <section name="pageTypeBuilderUI" type="PageTypeBuilderUI.Configuration.PageTypeBuilderUIConfiguration, PageTypeBuilderUI" />
  </configSections>
  <pageTypeBuilder disablePageTypeUpdation="true" />

Comment: http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Lee-Crowe/Dates/2011/7/Introducing-Page-Type-Builder-UI/ - This plugin points out discrepancies between PageTypeBuilder page type properties and EPiServer page type definitions and allows you to edit or remove them.

Answer (score 3):

Everytime the application starts, pagetypebuilder check if you have new properties/page types and adds them to the database.

Comment: That's my experience too. I.e. if you delete a page type through the admin interface, it won't reappear until you restart the application.